# Apache configuration for slim3 with ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, slim-3

I'm trying to setup my apache configuration file with my slim framework application to use ssl. I've done this in the past but for whatever reason, I'm getting 404 errors when I try to access any page other than the home page. Here is my apache configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.my-site.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    ServerAdmin my.email@gmail.com
    ServerName www.my-site.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privkey.pem

    ServerAdmin my.email@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /wwwroot/sites/my-site/public
    ServerName www.my-site.com
    ErrorLog logs/www.my-site.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/www.my-site.com-access_log common

    <Directory "/wwwroot/sites/my-site/public">
        AllowOverride All

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /wwwroot/sites/my-site/public
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As stated, my home page works exactly as I'd expect it to work. But when I try to go to https://www.my-site.com/another/page, I get a 404 error.

I have a dev version of this project set up on another server that doesn't use https and I have no problems going to http://dev.my-site.com/another/page.

Answer (score 0):

try set `RewriteBase` to `/`

```
<Directory "/wwwroot/sites/my-site/public">
    AllowOverride All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```